# Combine multiple csv file along column

Tags: csv, merge

I need to combine multiple .CSV files along the column. I tried using the power query function in excel but only be able to add along rows below, but I want to add on the column side.

Comment: A [example] would help immensely (toy data and expected result, at the very least), as well as the description of the "many methods" you tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "along the column", like add CSVs "under" each other?

Comment: I mean, to make one CSV or Excel file where all data are added on the right sides.

Comment: Sounds like the **zip** command for the command-line utility I'm recommending could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The command-line tool GoCSV has a number of commands for combining multiple CSVs.

The two that I think might help you are [stack](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#stack) to add CSVs on top of each other, and [zip](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#stack) to add CSVs side-by-side.

#### stack

For these two input CSVs:

```
input1.csv     input2.csv
  H1,H2          H1,H2
   A, 1           C, 3
   B, 2           D, 4
```

When I run `gocsv stack input1.csv input2.csv` it writes input1.csv, then input2.csv as new rows underneath it, discarding the header from input2:

```
H1,H2
 A, 1
 B, 2
 C, 3
 D, 4
```

The headers have to match for all input files for **stack** to work.

#### zip

For these two input CSVs:

```
input1.csv     input2.csv
  H1,H2          H3,H4
   A, 1           C, 3 
   B, 2           D, 4 
                  E, 5
```

When I run `gocsv zip input1.csv input2.csv` it writes input1.csv, then input2.csv as new columns to the right.  Columns can be different, and there can be different numbers of rows, too:

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
 A, 1, C, 3
 B, 2, D, 4
  ,  , E, 5
```

#### join

It also has a [join](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#join) command which matches rows from different CSVs by *key* columns.

In the samples below I want to join up the Roman numerals to the decimal numbers, and I'll use the first column as the key that matches for both inputs:

```
input1.csv     input2.csv
  H1, H2         H1,  H2
   A,  1          C, III 
   B,  2          B,  II 
   C,  3          A,   I
```

When I run `gocsv join -c H1 input1.csv input2.csv` it matches each row from both files by the capital letter in the H1 column.  It also rearranged the rows from input2 to match the order of the rows from input1:

```
H1, H2, H1,  H2
 A,  1,  A,   I
 B,  2,  B,  II
 C,  3,  C, III
```

It has a number of pre-compiled binaries.  You can check for your OS, download, and give it a try.